# How can I use Arabic or Persian Calendar in Oracle Mobile Application Framework (MAF)?

Tags: arabic, jdeveloper, mobile-application, persian, oracle-maf

I'm developing Mobile Applications with Oracle MAF in JDeveloper.
in some Pages I want to use Persian/Arabic Calendar for getting date from user.

how can I use Persian/Arabic Calendars/InputDate?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. On JDeveloper, select the Applications folder or any project folder and then select Preferences from the Tools menu.
2. On Preferences, select Environment.
3. In the Environment pane, select UTF8 from the Encoding drop-down list box.
4. Click OK.

All projects in the workspace show **UTF8** as the value for the Encoding field when you select Preferences from the Tools menu.

1. To configure default project properties to support UTF-8:
2. On JDeveloper, select the Applications folder, the workspace folder, or any project folder, and then select Project Properties from the Tools menu.
3. In the navigation pane on Project Properties, select Compiler.
4. In the Compiler pane, select UTF8 from the Character Encoding drop-down list box.
5. Click OK.

To configure a project to support UTF-8:

1. On JDeveloper, right-click the project folder that will include non-English data, and then select Project Properties from the context menu.
2. In the navigation pane on Project Properties, select Compiler.
3. In the Compiler pane, select UTF8 from the Character Encoding drop-down list box.
4. Only the selected project shows UTF8 as the value for the Character Encoding field.
5. Restart JDeveloper.

You can insert non-English data and run your project.

you can get the more information from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17984_01/doc.898/e14693/appa_configuring_jdev.htm)  or [here](http://www.serkey.com/oracle-arabic-characters-in-java-with-jdeveloper-bcqbta.html)

Hope it Help.
Thanks

Comment: @Zoya please help me to using the oepe, need to add malayalam font in amx pages - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28695716/how-to-include-custom-font-in-oracle-maf-oepe