# How to include custom font in Oracle MAF OEPE

Tags: fonts, oracle-maf

I am completely new to the Oracle MAF, I am using the OEPE environment to develop the app. I want to include native font files in the application (Like what we do in android - include it in assets folder and refer to the file in program). I failed to find any useful data about it except this link
https://community.oracle.com/message/12669272#12669272

unfortunatly I am not enough familiar with this to understand, please help me i need to add native language text to the header and for a content text  int the amf page( not an html page ), please help me....

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the article at
http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/mobile201/mobile/develop-oepe/oepe-maf-ui-components.htm#CHDGIBAC
in order to read more about skinning.

You can create a new css file with the font and override the default css style in a that css file. Then include the css file in maf-skins.xml (under ApplicationController/src/META-INF) folder.
Please import and run the SkinningDemo (New > MAF Examples) to see how the default skin can be extended/altered.

Thanks